# How do I work with Oracle Mobile Database Server for my android app?

Tags: android, database, oracle, server

I am creating an Android Database Application using Oracle Mobile Database Server. I am following the transport tutorial provided by Oracle. In the tutorial they are publishing the app to the mobile server and then launching the mobile manager in the phone's browser to download Oracle Database Mobile Server client and Transport.apk using the client. I need to know how can we do all this stuff programmatically? If I upload my app on PlayStore, then after installing the app, how do I download Oracle Database Mobile Server client and fill in the details such as username and password in the client programmatically?